# Automatic height for XIB and container views

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, interface-builder, xcode8

I'm trying to build reusable views for my storyboard, let's start with the XIB:

[image: XIB TextField on Interface Builder]

This view contains a UITextField with a label to show a error, the File's Owner is connected to this class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class TextField: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var errorLine: UIImageView!

    var view: UIView!

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "TextField", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        return view
    }

    func xibSetup() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        xibSetup()
    }

    @IBInspectable var placeholder: String? {
        didSet {
            textField.placeholder = placeholder
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var isSecureTextEntry: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            textField.isSecureTextEntry = isSecureTextEntry
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var errorText: String? {
        didSet {
            errorLabel.text = errorText
        }
    }

    func showError() {
        errorLine.isHidden = false
        errorLabel.isHidden = false
    }

    func hideError() {
        errorLine.isHidden = true
        errorLabel.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Then I use this on Main.storyboard as UIView, setting the class to TextField:

[image]

The problem here is that I need to add a constraint for the height every time I use this TextField class, I tried with the instrinsic size as Placeholder for the UIView on the Main.storyboard (removing the height constraint) but at runtime doesn't have the same height of the XIB.

The same problem happens with the Container View for a View Controller, I have this situation:

[image]

How can I make the Container View be the same height of the view controller that is embed inside? (as a test, I made the big red view controller be 1500px in height to see if it scrolled, if I put a constraint on the height of the container view the content size of the scroll view is correct, but I want to avoid the constraint on the height, I want it to be automatic)

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: FWIW, I tried doing this same thing and it was painful. I ended up laying out my cell subview in code and then just specifying the height via constraints. I also had a need for the child view to control the height of the container, and couldn't figure out a better way than setting up a line of communication for it to communicate to the parent and change it manually via an NSLayoutConstraint. Not ideal, but certainly not an awful solution.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same technic I described here: 
https://medium.com/zenchef-tech-and-product/how-to-visualize-reusable-xibs-in-storyboards-using-ibdesignable-c0488c7f525d#.3c0javomy

Make sure all your constraints in your Xib define the height of your view.
When you use it in your storyboard, you shouldn't need to set the height again. However, you'll see IB constraints error in your storyboard until you render the views.